# Compare text in EditText with defined String?

Tags: android

i'm new with Android and i'm writing a simple alarm clock application.when i type the string into the EditText like this "10:00,Monday" this string will compare syntax with the defined string if true it'll turn on the AlarmClock. But i don't know how to compare. May you give me an idea? Thanks so much. My app's interface and code below

1.My app's interface https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40382482/Screenshot%20from%202012-10-25%2023%3A51%3A14.png

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   /* Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    final TextView labelDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDate);
    final TextView lableTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblTime);

    labelDate.setText(date.format(cal.getTime()));
    lableTime.setText(time.format(cal.getTime()));*/
    final ArrayList<String> setAlarm = new ArrayList<String>();
    //nhap noi dung vao edit text

    final EditText alarmEnter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setting);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Okay);

    OnClickListener add = new OnClickListener()
    { 

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(alarmEnter.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Info Missing");
                builder.setMessage("Please Enter All Information");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface diablog, int which)
                    {

                    }
                }
                        ); builder.show();
            }
            else {
                                //compare string in EditText and defined string?

            }
        }
    };
    button.setOnClickListener(add);
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you have written so far.

Comment: `if (myDefinedString.equals(myEditText.getText().toString()) { // do something }`

Comment: oh thank you! i'm trying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare one string with another, use:

```
if(strText.equals("myString")){ // strText is the string from the edit text, myString is the string
                               // you are comparing it to
  // do something

}else{

 // do something else
}
```

This will return a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

if (myEditText.getText().toString().equals(myString)) { ... }